# Excel unwanted behavior when using IF function

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, undefined-behavior

I'm lost on this one. My goal is to have a table conditionally fill itself out based on whether or not a certain cell has the letter "x" in it. Each remaining cell in the row contains one of three things: nothing, a "1", or a "0". When there is no "x" present in the designated cell, all 1's in that row become 0's. The blank spaces remain blank spaces. Here's what a given row looks like:

```
  A      B     C     D     E     F     G     H
Item 1   x     1           1     1           1
Item 2   x           1     1     1     1     
Item 3   x     1     1           1     1
```

And here's what should happen if I get rid of the "x" for Item 1:

```
  A      B     C     D     E     F     G     H
Item 1         0           0     0           0
Item 2   x           1     1     1     1     
Item 3   x     1     1           1     1
```

Unfortunately, I'm seeing some undefined behavior. If I remove one of the "x"s and press enter, the zeros populate in the right place and everything is fine. If I try adding that "x" back, however, the zeros turn back into ones AND some of the blank cells populate with ones. The weirdest thing is that not all of the blank cells populate with one, just seemingly random ones (though the same every time).

I checked those cells for any formulas, cleared the contents of those cells just to be safe, and I'm still seeing this behavior. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Forgot to post the formula I'm using. Each number cell has the following IF statement: =IF(B2="x",1,0)

Comment: Post your conditional format formula so people can take a look

Comment: @DanDonoghue good call, edited

Comment: If a cell is empty, then changing another cell won't magically create content in the empty cell. If you find that this is happening in your case, please upload that wonder file to a file sharing service for inspection. Also, if you copy the formula you posted to the right, it will adjust the relative reference `B2` to `C2` etc. when copied across. You may want to anchor it with `$B2` so the B stays a B

Comment: @TimWilliams Nobody but the commenters is talking about a conditional **format**. He has a worksheet formula, not a CF

Comment: @teylyn - yes I figured that out...

Comment: Yeah my bad, I misread `My goal is to have a table conditionally fill itself out`

Answer (score 0):

Niko,

From what I can tell a few things can be happening.

1) Make sure your empty cells are Empty. Or try to type ="" for those cells to see if that will keep them empty.

2) Make sure your formulas are automatically calculating.

Go to Formulas -> Calculation Options -> Automatic.

Otherwise I am not sure why you are getting strange values.